# Apiary Error when invoking API

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

I get the following error on ApiaryWe are sorry, but the API call failed.

My host is defined as 
FORMAT: 1A
HOST: https://test.mynetwork.com/

GET CALL IS DEFINED AS

### data urn [models/v2/files/{urn}/data{?guid}]

#### GET [GET]

- Parameters

  - urn (required, string, `ttt`)...design urn.
  - guid (optional, string,`067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dfe02`)...filter by guid.
- Response 200 (application/vnd.api+json)

  - Body
    data
        {
        "version": "1.0",
    }

When i invoke this , i get error . Any inputs

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your API Blueprint as follows:

```
FORMAT: 1A

HOST: https://test.mynetwork.com

# Test API

This is a test API

## data urn [/models/v2/files/{urn}/data{?guid}]

+ Parameters
    + urn: `ttt` (required, string) - design urn
    + guid: `067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dfe02` (optional, string) - filter by guid

### test [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/vnd.api+json)

        {
            "version": "1.0"
        }
```

You can find tutorials here: https://help.apiary.io/

Also not sure what you mean "invoke" the API - are you calling the mock server or are you hitting your own server through Apiary.

Happy to help further via the support option in Apiary itself or email us on support [at] apiary.io.

Comment: Thanks manp, it helped. My parameter values contained ':' which is not accepted. So changing the values of query parameter helped